# Prevent Docker from pulling remote repository

Tags: docker

When creating a container (docker create) is there a way to restrict docker engine to only use a local image, and not try a remote pull?

It seems like this would be a common requirement where you want tight control over container images. While it wouldn't be possible to actually load the wrong image due to security checks, I don't want to have it bother trying.

Comment: I mean ... that seems to go against the very purpose of docker?

Comment: And why would that be? You could have your own, private Docker registry and you don’t want to download any public images.

Answer (score 1):

For what I know, if an image exist localy, docker won't pull it automatically. You explicitly have to tell Docker to do so.

You could use a private registry, the image will be accessed through the hostname of the registry, so there won't be any "misunderstanding". One way could be to push all your images on a private registry, so you could only use you own "official" images, then maybe use a CI to check if you Dockerfile/docker-compose complies with your requirements?
You can even push images from the hub on a private registry, and retag them if you want to, if I am not mistaken.

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that `docker run` does **not** provide any flag to avoid pulling from **remote** repository.

It's possible to run image `$NAME` after checking if it exists

```
docker image inspect $NAME > /dev/null && docker run $NAME
```

- try to get info about image to check if exists locally `docker image inspect`
- skip output `> /dev/null`
- if succeeded, then image exists locally `exit code 0`
- run image `docker run`

Answer (score 0):

How about (for EG) :

```
docker load < /var/tmp/b_jira2.tar.xz
docker run --name b_jira -d -p 8080:8080 b_jira
```